# what is conditional probabiltiy

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**what is exactly is the conditional probability**
I saw this this kind of definitions for conditional probability

> **Definition:**
> Conditional probability is the likelihood
> of an event occurring based on the occurrence of a previous event.

and some definitions follows like this

> **Definition:**
> $P(E|F) = P(EF)/P(F)$ (where $P(F) \neq 0$.)
> I saw the same formula in the first definition

I don't know which definition is defined first
**if 1 st definition is defined first then how do we came to the formula from the definition. or if 2nd definition (formula ) defined first than what does that formula actually says**

in other words my question is **what is the relation between the statement and formula**
and I want to know this because that independent events are defined from this formula.

and one thing what does p(A|B) mean.

And additional question is **what is this bayes theorem?**

Comment: See [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) and [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). Is there something specific you're having trouble understanding? Have you thought about any examples? If you roll a 6-sided die, given that you get an odd number, what's the probability that you get a 1?

Comment: i know this equation here s my doubt is can you prove this formula from LHS and what is the relation between the formal definition of conditional probability and this formula (P(E|F)=P(EF)/P(F) (where P(F)≠0 .) and i know that bayes theorem is derived from the this same formula. 1/6 is the answer (i assuming that you are trying to answer me from the scratch thats why i answered ur question.)

Comment: Given that you got an odd number, there are only 3 possibilities, so the *conditional* probability you got a 1 is $1/3$. Do you see how this relates to the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I perceive it, you are unable to grasp how the formula $P(E|F) = P(EF)/P(F)$ (where $P(F) \neq0$ ) actually gives the conditional probability of $E$ occurring given that $F$ has ocurred.

Please go to the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) and Venn Diagram of sets of creatures with two legs ($E$.say) and creatures that can fly.($F$)

The common region (intersection) is $EF$,

So if I ask what is the probability that the creature is two legged **given** that it can fly,notation $P(E|F)$  obviously it is the fraction of flyers who are two legged, ie $P(EF)/P(F)$

Thus $P(E|F) = P(EF)/P(F)$ expresses in a precise formula the conditional probability of $E$ given that $F$ has occurred.

If you look at the diagram again, you could also compute $P(F|E) = P(EF)/P(E)$,

so you can see that $P(EF) = P(E|F)*P(F) = P(F|E)*P(E)$

Bayes' Theorem  converts one conditional probability to another, eg  from P(E|F) to P(F|E)

A prime example is in disease testing. Suppose a COVID test has tested positive for you, P(Positive|Diseased), you want to know instead P(Diseased | Positive), you will need to use Bayes' Theorem, about you can read a bit more [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Comment: i think now i got it do you mean that let there are two events (A and B) .I know that event B is occurring now I want to know occurs of event A in this condition which is 
n(A intersection B)/n(B) = (n(A intersection B)/n(S))/(n(B)/n(S))=P(A intersection B)/P(B).
and from  this we can prove the bayes theorem P(EF)=P(E|F)∗P(F)=P(F|E)∗P(E).
now what I want to know is when do P(A|B)=P(A)(what is independent event ) btw way thanks for you answer

Comment: Glad to be of help !$\quad P(A|B) = P(A)$ shows that the probability of event $A$ is not affected by event $B$ occurring, so $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Comment: i think its only possible when B is a sample space so does it mean A,B are independents only when B is sample space it doesnt make sense (i think i misunderstood something can you explain where did i went and going wrong)

Comment: @QweBoss: No, here the sample space is $(A \cup B)$, see the link in the answer for the example of the Venn Diagram

Comment: which link ?????

Comment: @QweBoss: Click on blue coloured "example" in the second para of the answer